# Dataframe reshape to a new strucutre - R

Tags: r

I got this text file (located in https://pastebin.com/R7U6kYJN) and I read it using read.delim. The structure of the file is repeated: Line 1 – XYLM, Lines 2 – 15 X Y coordinates, Line 16 - Image Source, Line 17 – ID No, Line 18 - Scale

How can I convert the data to another dataframe with these headers
ImageSource, IDNo, XYLM, X1, Y1,…, X14, Y14, Scale?

I wrote the attached code but its just getting more and more messy as for the X1, Y1,…, X14, Y14 I will need another loop.

Code:

```
GIS_Data <- read.delim("E:/try.txt",header = FALSE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(i in seq(1,nrow(GIS_Data), by = 18)) {
  XYLM <- GIS_Data[i, 1]
  ImageSource <- GIS_Data[i+15, 1]
  Scale <- GIS_Data[i+17, 1]
  IDNo <- GIS_Data[i+16, 1]
  XYCoord <- unlist(strsplit(GIS_Data[i+1, 1], " "))
  Xn <- XYCoord[1]
  Yn <- XYCoord[2]
}
```

Comment: What's the source of the data as there's usually already a package that has addressed the particular format.

Comment: But anyway, dput(head( , n = 18)) and what do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming data perpectly repeated and no missing value, you can do it without a loop.

**Read txt**

```
GIS_Data  <- readLines("try.txt")
```

**Extract from line having char `=`**

```
library(tidyverse)

extract_info <- function(pattern){
  str_extract_all(GIS_Data, paste0(pattern, "=.*")) %>% 
    unlist %>% 
    str_split("=") %>% 
    sapply("[[",2)
}

ImageSource = extract_info("ImageSource")
IDNo = extract_info("IDNo")
XYLM = extract_info("XYLM")
Scale = extract_info("Scale")
```

**Extract XY**

```
XY <- GIS_Data %>% 
  str_extract_all("[\\d.]+ [\\d.]+") %>% 
  unlist %>% str_split(" ") %>%
  unlist %>% matrix(ncol = 28, byrow = T) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  setNames(., paste(rep(c("X","Y"), 14), rep(1:14,each=2), sep=""))
```

**Combine**

```
GIS_Data_reshaped <- cbind(ImageSource, IDNo, XYLM, XY, Scale)
```

**Output**

```
GIS_Data_reshaped

#   ImageSource IDNo XYLM        X1        Y1        X2         Y2        X3        Y3
# 1     002.tif   0    14 111.00000 743.00000 246.00000 1359.00000 383.00000 728.00000
# 2     004.tif   1    14  98.00000 681.00000 233.00000 1297.00000 354.00000 705.00000
# 3     005.tif   2    14 136.00000 618.00000 248.00000 1109.00000 355.00000 617.00000
#          X4        Y4        X5        Y5        X6        Y6        X7        Y7        X8
# 1 251.00000  77.00000 311.00000 748.00000 253.00000 767.00000 256.00000 701.00000 229.00000
# 2 238.00000  99.00000 299.00000 707.00000 228.00000 743.00000 223.00000 682.00000 195.00000
# 3 251.00000 113.00000 298.00000 649.00000 240.00000 656.00000 243.00000 612.00000 221.00000
#          Y8        X9        Y9       X10        Y10       X11        Y11       X12
# 1 788.00000 224.00000 712.00000 144.00000 1002.00000 201.00000 1318.00000 161.00000
# 2 748.00000 197.00000 694.00000 126.00000  963.00000 188.00000 1256.00000 275.00000
# 3 657.00000 218.00000 611.00000 161.00000  882.00000 208.00000 1079.00000 284.00000
#          Y12       X13       Y13       X14       Y14    Scale
# 1  408.00000 453.00000 216.00000 452.00000  31.00000   0.0216
# 2 1258.00000 326.00000 955.00000 316.00000 391.00000 0.164216
# 3 1080.00000 331.00000 877.00000 312.00000 323.00000  0.01116
```